# Pandas, Equivalent to "Not Like"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a where clause in my pandas dataframe.

my original code filters out the word "ALL".

```
combineQueryandBookFiltered = CombineQueryandBook[(CombineQueryandBook.excludeFromAggregation != 'ALL')]
```

But i am now trying to add a second condition, where positionId is **not like** (or doesnt start with) "Manual", currently I have it where it is NOT "Manual":

```
combineQueryandBookFiltered = CombineQueryandBook[(CombineQueryandBook.excludeFromAggregation != 'ALL') | CombineQueryandBook[(CombineQueryandBook.positionId != 'Manual') ]]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but wouldn't changing the '|' to '&' solve your problem?

Comment: You have a superfluous `CombineQueryandBook[...]` in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.startswith()` method

```
CombineQueryandBook[
    (CombineQueryandBook.excludeFromAggregation != 'ALL') &
    ~CombineQueryandBook.positionId.str.startswith('Manual')
]
```